# Google Firebase Auth Failed on Netlify, But work on local server

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, netlify

When I deploy my site to netlify, I cannot sign in properly, new google window open and close automatically, my site [Clock](https://kreivc-clock.netlify.app/)

```
function SignIn() {
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
};

return (
  <>
    <button className="sign" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
      Sign in with Google
    </button>
  </>
);
```

}

```
function SignOut() {
return (
  auth.currentUser && (
    <button className="sign" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>
      Sign Out
    </button>
  )
);
```

}

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhzN2.jpg)

It only happen in web after I deploy it on netlify, and works normally in local server

Comment: Did you add the netlify domain to the allow list on the firebase console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your current netlify domain to firebase console

First go this url : https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/your_project_name/authentication/providers

Then go to `Authorised domains` section and add https://kreivc-clock.netlify.app/

Always remember to check for auth errors and alert it :

```
const signIn = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above provided a link which is currently giving a error message like this "***There was an unknown error while processing the request.***". As an amateur I was struggling finding the **`Authorized Domains`** option(Google might move the route over time to time).

This is How I **`Solved`** the problem:
First go to the : https://console.firebase.google.com/

If you are signed in you will see all of your projects list here. **Select** the project for which you want to add **Authorized Domain**. A Project overview page will be opened.

Then click on the **`Authentication`** link on the left side  under the **`Project Overview`** Button or under the **`Project Shortcuts`** label.

On the new page You will see a button **`Settings`** on the right side of **`User`**, **`Sign in method`** Options. After Clicking the **`Setting`** button you will finally see **`Authorized Domain`** option at the bottom of the page. Now you can add your domain(like you provided: *https://kreivc-clock.netlify.app/*) here. You problem with **Netlify and Google Auth** will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

this is the latest way to fix it 2023
i fixed mine by going to authentication -> settings -> look down you will see the authorized domain click it an

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

go to firebase console: https://console.firebase.google.com/ and in your app authentication settings  add your domain name like https://main.d3fhwgmscd8m7w.amplifyapp.com/